# Conditioning without if - Django python

Tags: python, django

I want to choose one thing or the other but I can't use an if statement since an error occurs even if i just try it.

How can i structure the code so that if possible, I do this:

```
i = Image(entry = e,\
        image = request.FILES['file'],))
i.save()
```

and if it wasn't possible, I should do this instead:

```
i = Image(entry = e,\
        url = request.POST['website'])
i.save()
```

The basic thing I'm actually checking is if i can call request.FILES, since my image is either just a URL or a local file itself, but I can't try it in an if statement.

Thank you

Comment: by the way: there is no need for the line continuation backslash here.

Comment: You should show the if statement you tried, and skew the error, before asking for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
kw = {'entry': e}
if 'file' in request.FILES:
    kw['image'] = request.FILES['file']
elif 'url' in request.POST:
    kw['url'] = request.POST['website']
else:
    raise SomeException()
i = Image(**kw)
i.save()
```

but you'd be better using a `Form` or `ModelForm` with custom validation...

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    i = Image(entry = e,\
        image = request.FILES['file'],))
    i.save()

 except:
    i = Image(entry = e,\
        url = request.POST['website'])
    i.save()
```

Comment: don't use just an empty `except`, only catch what you're looking for.

Comment: Ryan is correct, I meant to put that but I wasn't sure what type of error you were receiving.

Comment: @Alecg_O: it's quite easy to find out... Both are instance of `MultiValueDict` (well, `request.POST` is actually a `QueryDict`, which is a subclass of `MultiValueDict`, and this will raise a `MultiValueDictKeyError`, which is actually a subclass of the builtin `KeyError`. TL;DR : you get a `KeyError`...